# css class and id on UL

Tags: css

How do i write the same when the ul is a class instead of id?

```
 ul#Menu li a{}


 ul.Menu li a{}  not working properly
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML it goes with that's not getting styled?

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly right, so if it isn't working the problem is in some of the code you aren't showing us